# Difference between Bash, Shell, UXTerm and Terminal

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

In Windows we have Command Prompt but on linux there is more simmilar "apps" like:

- Shell
- UXTerm
- Terminal
- and maybe more

This is my first day on linux, can someone describe difference between that?

Comment: Sorry, this is a place for _programming_ questions. You might want to ask your question on http://superuser.com if google really cannot answer those questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In linux they can all look the same from the point of view of the user at the keyboard. The differences are in how they interact with each other.

The **shell** is the program which actually processes commands and returns output. Most shells also manage foreground and background processes, command history and command line editing. These features (and many more) are standard in bash, the most common shell in modern linux systems.
A **terminal** refers to a wrapper program which runs a shell. Decades ago, this was a physical device consisting of little more than a monitor and keyboard. As unix/linux systems added better multiprocessing and windowing systems, this terminal concept was abstracted into software. Now you have programs such as Gnome Terminal which launches a window in a Gnome windowing environment which will run a shell into which you can enter commands.

 **UXTerm** is XTerm with support to Unicode characters. The main difference between XTerm and Terminal is that the gnome-terminal has more features, while XTerm is minimalistic (though it has features that are't in gnome-terminal, but they are more advanced).

Comment: And UXTerm, XTerm, Konsole, rxvt and a bunch of others are examples of terminal programs.

Comment: @Up_One You might want to add that Terminal can both refer to the "concept" of terminal (you do already) but also a software that emulates the behavior of the original physical device. Most "terminal" programs that exist nowadays are called "terminal emulators".

Comment: @Unode - great straightforward definition.

Answer (score 0):

A shell in computing provides a user interface for access to an operating system's services. They can be a command line interface (this is the terminal in Linux or the command line in windows) or the graphical interface, (the desktop, icons, folders, windows, ect).